# Create table with auto increment

Tags: sqlite

I have to create a table with autoincrement column. I am creating an web app with sqlite as a background and sql alchemy is the orm layer.Python and Flask as front end. I am creating some department list and department id should be auto incremented.When I try to add department through UI I dont provide department id.Because department id is the primary key and should be auto incremented.I have added the department name and department jobs through UI without any error.But when I try to list the departments list I am getting error.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'department_id'

What I tried is,My sqlite

```
create table Departments(department_id primarykey integer autoincrement,department_name char,department_jobs char);
```

When I try creating this schema I am getting an error called 'syntax error near autoincrement'

I tried by using capital letter,auto_increment,auto increment.

Nothing is working

My sql alchemy looks like this

```
class Departments(db.Model):
    "Adding the department" 
    department_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)   
    department_name = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)   
    department_jobs = db.Column(db.String(40),nullable=False)
```

What I am expecting here is how do I do the auto incrementin sqllite and sqlalchemy so that I can use it in both frontend and backend.

Comment: Note that all you need is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and not providing a value for that column when inserting rows to get automatically generated values. The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword simply changes the algorithm used to compute the numbers, and indeed it's suggested that it's not used unless you explicitly *need* its specific behavior. See https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have coded PRIMARYKEY instead of **PRIMARY KEY** and you should also code **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** as the **column type** should appear first.

There is no need, from your explanation, to code AUTOINCREMENT.

Not using AUTOINCREMENT will be more efficient and will as far as you are concerned do the same thing. i.e. if the value for the department_id is not supplied, then SQLite will automatically generate a value which will be 1 for the first row that is inserted and then typically 1 greater for the next row and so on (SQLite does not guarantee montonically increasing numbers).

[SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) which includes

> The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.

I'd sugggest just using :-

```
create table Departments(department_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,department_name char,department_jobs char);
```